# Регулярка не все вырезает

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
 kolichestvo-nomerov=1|||tip-ego=1|||pod=1|||adres=Сапфира, 92
```

Сама регулярка:

```
 preg_replace("#adres\|||(.+?)\|||\|#is",'',$ds['pole'])
```

на выходе получаем:

```
 adres=Сапфира, 92
```

Как еще вырезать этот кусок: `adres=`, чтобы в итоге стало так:`Сапфира, 92`

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, [проголосуйте за него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно решить это следующим образом: найти весь текст до последнего знака `=` с помощью `~.*=~s` и удалить его:

```
$s = 'kolichestvo-nomerov=1|||tip-ego=1|||pod=1|||adres=Сапфира, 92';
echo preg_replace("~.*=~s",'', $s, 1);
// => Сапфира, 92
```

Можно найти текст после последнего знака `=` с помощью `~=\K[^=]+$~` (тут после `=`, который убирается из совпадения с помощью оператора `\K`, находятся 1 и более знаков, отличных от `=`, после которых сразу следует конец строки):

```
if (preg_match('~=\K[^=]+$~', $s, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
} // => Сапфира, 92
```

См. [PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/1h6iHw).